# how to pass JSON data to view in laravel

Tags: json, laravel, view

I want to pass this JSON data to some view but don't know how its works.

I have used, make view also, and convert this data to JSON and pass other way but it didn't work

```
$items = Items::all();
return response()->JSON($items);
```

e.g view is `items.create`

Comment: open chrome dev tools, go to network tab, make the request and inspect the response. also post more code i.e routes.

Comment: for passing to the view:
`$items = Items::all();`
`return view('items.create', compact('items'));`
for getting json data only :
`$items = Items::all();`
`return $items;`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create [JSON response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#json-responses), you need to convert collection to an array:

```
$items = Items::all()->toArray(); // $items is array now
return response()->json($items);
```

If you want to pass some [JSON data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json) to a view, do this:

```
$items = Items::all()->toJson();
return view('items.create', compact('items'));
```

Comment: its not showing anything in console , i'm working with angular JS here is the code  `$scope.init = function() {
         $http({
            method  : 'GET',
            url     : 'http://localhost:8000/item'
         }) .success(function(data) {

               console.log(data);
         });
      }`

Answer (score 3):

For Laravel ver 4.2,
You can pass your data to your **blade** view with a variable (eg:$data) having an array which will be used in your blade.

$flag is variable being used in the JS part of your code, so you can pass that also as an array: `Response::json(['param1' => $foo1, 'param2' =>$foo2)]);`

In your controller return the view:

```
 return Response::json(['view' => View::make('yourbladename', $data)->render(), 'flag'=>$flag]);
```

In your JS use the data variables as:

```
function(data){     
 $('#DivToAppendHTML').append(data.view);                    //this appends html blade to the Div having the ID DivToAppendHTML
       if(data.flag == 1){                                  //this uses the second variable passed in controller for any other purpose
                       $('.classname').remove();
        }
}
```